# Correct Approach to Populating a Table View Using An Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm currently trying to implement a Table View on my iPhone app that grabs an array from one table view/class and using this array to populate a table in another seperate view. Here is the method I use that adds an exercise to an array if it is clicked/tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSUInteger *index = 0;

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array insertObject:str atIndex:index];

    self.workout = array;

    [array release];
}
```

Once the save button is pressed, this array will be stored in an array of workouts (arrays) that I want to be populated in another view. Am I taking the correct approach this?

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SectionsTableIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier: SectionsTableIdentifier ] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for this tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably do not want to re-initialize `self.workout` with a new array each time.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  self.workout = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;
    [self.workout insertObject:str atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to implement a seperate save workout method that stores the current instance of workout into another array, then empties the array?